# Hadoop MapReduce affected by using different hardware

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I have been using Hadoop for a while using Python for streaming MapReduce tasks.

I will have 2 fast servers and I wanted to add some other hardware of various specs. I was wondering would it slow down adding slower machines to the cluster.

Can or does the splitting of the work adapt to the processing power of the node. 
Is the work divided equally over a node total or is a task sent as and when the machine has finished the last task, is there a way to control any of this

thanks
Martin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop MapReduce (Yarn) usign hosts with different power/specifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840962/hadoop-mapreduce-yarn-usign-hosts-with-different-power-specifications)